# tripp-lite kvm B022-U16-IP factory default reset

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse, reset

It's the weekend and tripp-lite support not available. I have a B022-U16-IP KVM, i used default password and set a new ip adress and re--logged in via web with default passwords. I replaced adminsitrator user and rebooted - and now cannot log in with new user or adminsarator. I have tried a variety of reset presses on the front panel pin button (twice in 2 seconds, with power on and off, holding for over 20 seconds), the button responds and reboots the device but it is still on the new ip and wont login. How to clear back to factory defaults?

Answer (score 2):

a) when typing passwords in web browser it will not take " ! " exclamation marks.

b) for benefit of others, you can clear by openign the case with power off. THere is supposed to be a jumber for "Default password" on the main board J17 near the screw holding board down. Short jumper and power on - then power off and remove jumper.